# Update post meta date always store 1970-01-07

Tags: post-meta, date

I want to update the post meta "job_expires" to the current "job_expires" meta data + 1 week but with this code always store 1970-01-07 as date.

```
$lejar_datum = get_post_meta($job_id , '_job_expires', true);
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('+1 week',$lejar_datum));
update_post_meta( $job_id, '_job_expires', $date);
```

How can I store the current "job_expires" date + 1 week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With debugging enabled, you should have gotten the following message:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

This is because [`strtotime()` expects an integer as its second argument](https://php.net/strtotime). You could use it like so

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 week', strtotime($lejar_datum)));
```

or if you want to use the more modern approach with `DateTime`

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $lejar_datum)->modify('+1 week');
update_post_meta($job_id, '_job_expires', $dt->format('Y-m-d'));
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and your help!